# git rebase -i HEAD ~n gives error unexpected EOF while looking for matching ''

Tags: git

I am trying to amend older commit message. As per Git's instruction page, When I type following
    git rebase -i HEAD~3
I am getting following error.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.5/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: eval: line 245: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.4.5/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: eval: line 246: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Could not execute editor
```

I had older version of Git(2.2.1) and I updated it through "brew upgrade Git" 
but still the problem persists.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check `~/.gitconfig` in particular under `[core]` make sure that your `editor` value is set correctly for your system.

My guess is that it is failing to launch the editor for interactive rebasing due to a bad command or parameter.

Comment: The line 245 on git-rebase--interactive file is:  eval "$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR" '"$@"' . Should '$@' this be changed to something?

Comment: No, that part is correct. It's the value that it is pulling from your config that is probably causing the issue

Comment: I figured it out. There was a " ' " missing in my .gitconfig file. Thanks Andrew.